# Is it thread-safe to read but not write a shared variable?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Using Pthreads, suppose there is a global shared variable `foo` between threads 1 and 2. Is it thread-safe to read the value of `foo` from thread 1 without using a mutex? Note that while thread 1 reads `foo`, it is not impossible that thread 2 may be changing its value (but it would have locked the mutex beforehand of course).

The situation is something like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
...
int foo;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
...

void *thread1(void *t) {
  while (foo<10) {
    // do stuff
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *thread1(void *t) {
  ...
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  ...
  foo++;
  ...
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  ...
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think you need to lock both reads and writes.  If you don't, there's a possibility of "dirty reads".

Comment: Your example isn't clear since you show two functions `thread1()`.  Presumably, you meant to use `thread1()` and `thread2()`, or something similar.  There's no guarantee that writes are atomic in general, so you need to protect access to `foo` with a mutex for both reading and writing.  It would be a more serious problem if `foo` were a structure type.  But the only safe (sane) strategy is to lock the mutex before reading or writing the shared variable.

Answer (score 3):

It is not thread safe for a variety of possible reasons, but the one you will likely run into is that the compiler could very well optimize the read of `foo` into a single read that is hoisted out of the while loop so it will never see a change.

Comment: Interesting point..  What restrictions do compilers have to the level of optimization that can be applied to something protected by a mutex ?

Comment: I don't know all the various factors that might come into play, but the main one is that the call to the function that acquires a mutex will result in the compiler having to reload the variable since as far as the compiler knows the variable could have been modified by the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you R/W a value you should sync the writes and the reads, that's because that can make inconsistent reads, like at the start you wanna read `foo = 0`, but write goes faster so you'll read `foo = 1`.

In your context that would be having less than 10 iterations in that while, so it's **NOT THREAD-SAFE**.

Comment: I'm not sure of this is a problem in my application though... I don't care how many iterations the `while` loop has - just that it quits when `foo` is really `>=10`. The concern is more that non locking the mutex for reading may be vulnerable to reading some nonsense, like an empty memory slot of something....

Comment: I've explianded how not use mutex makes 'reading some nonsense'

Comment: I don't see where you explained it... if write goes faster and I read foo=1, that's not a problem - it just means foo=1 now. A problem would be if somehow I read foo=2981232391 (bad memory access of some sort)

Comment: If inconsistent data is not a problem, then if foo is initialized it won't read any trash memory result. But my answer is that because you asked for thread-safe, and it's not thread-safe